# facebook submission for login and email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have created a small website for my weeding and i'm using facebook to login my friends and grab their email address.

all the functionality is already in place, and i can login fine because I'm a developer.

when i try to submit the app for review, they have rejected me 2 times because i was using the user_about_me permission (that i dont need) so i deleted the app and created a new one.

the status & review section says thatpublic_profile and user_email are approved by default, which are the only information that i need.

but i cant start a submission without selecting another permission, but i dont need them!

and they rejected me if i select something that I'm not using.

how can i get my web published??

Comment: _Because_ `public_profile` and `user_email` are approved by default, you do __not__ need to submit for review at all to be able to ask for those two permissions …

Comment: it says i haven't configured the application properly: "Not Authorized"

look you can try it yourself, www.reservaeldia.net

and if you debug it in the content/angular/maincontroller.js the  login function the response throws an error. :( but if i do it it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that you set your app public?

Comment: i was an idiot i needed to hit the public switch thanks :)